# App compiled with Pyinstaller failing to launch on other machines (OSError: dlopen() failed to load a library)

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller, cairo, software-distribution

I am developing a small app for MacOS with python 3.7. I installed the python with Homebrew. I compiled the app with PyInstaller. The app makes use of external libraries such as cairosvg and python-docx that PyInstaller does not seem to like. I've managed to make it work on my machine by moving the cairosvg and docx folders from their respective site-packages folders to the app distributive.

When I run the app on my machine (MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6), it works. When my client runs it on his machine (MacOS High Sierra 10.13.5), it crashes. I asked them to run it in the terminal to get the error messages, here is what they are getting:

```
Last login: Sat Oct 6 07:05:44 on console
Andrews-MacBook-Pro-3:~ perryand$ /Users/perryand/Downloads/PGN\ to\ docx/dist/main.app/Contents/MacOS/main ; exit;
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
File "cairosvg/init.py", line 41, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
File "cairosvg/surface.py", line 24, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
File "cairocffi/init.py", line 41, in <module>
File "cairocffi/init.py", line 38, in dlopen
OSError: dlopen() failed to load a library: cairo / cairo-2 / cairo-gobject-2
[15441] Failed to execute script main
logout
Saving session...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
Deleting expired sessions...none found.

[Process completed]
```

It seems like the cairosvg library fails to load. I did not have this error on my machine. Is there something I'm not including in the distributive that is very important for cairo? From my understanding, PyInstaller doesn't copy over unconventional files, but then it shouldn't work on my machine either. I tested it in a virtualenv with nothing installed, it worked and did not produce any errors. I am a bit lost.

Comment: Can you show the line 14 of `main.py`? It looks like you have a [hidden import](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports) which is not resolved by PyInstaller at build time; if this is the case, you need to write a [hook](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/hooks.html) that explicitly includes missing libs.

Comment: @hoefling

Line 14 is this:
import cairosvg.svg